# Model.create does not work on very large array of documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am facing a problem with mongoose Model.create method.

When i call

```
Model.create(arrayOfThousandDocs, function(err){});
```

After 15 min (sufficient for all the docs to get saved) when i switch to mongo shell and query upon total no of docs saved

then i find only something around 700-800 (no of docs saved varies every time Model.create is called).

And mongoose or mongo returns no any error.

Have anyone faced the same bug?
Please tell me how to resolve it.

Comment: That should work fine.  Enable Mongoose debug logging to see what's going on during the call by adding `mongoose.set('debug', true);` to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it may be because, Model.create uses forEach method, and that is not suitable in nodejs asynchronous mode programming.. Please correct me if if i am wrong..

and suggest your views..

here is the source : http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with using `forEach` in an async context; I think the issue here is that `Model.create` isn't suitable for bulk saving of thousands of documents. You should probably split your dataset up in batches of a couple of 100 docs max, or use the MongoDB driver directly instead of going though Mongoose.

Comment: why do need to restrict to 100.? and By the way with 100, i get 80-90 records saved checked from mongo shell.

Comment: Storing 1500 simple docs using `Model.create()` works just fine for me, they all end up in the DB. So apparently has to do with your setup or the type of documents you're saving.